# Set spinbox location JQuery Mobile (css)

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

Just can't figure out how to place this spinbox in the top-right corner, with the same margins as te top-left button. This is as far as I can get, but the header seems to be gone with this method. Also tried with setting the properties with jQuery after the DOM load, placed inside  etc.. Can someone please help me with this, placing it **inside** the dark-grey header with the same margins as the "terug" button? My current HTML code is below, and the current situation aswell as how I want it also are below.

```
<div data-role="page" id="RoomList">
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <%--<h1>Ruimten</h1>--%>
    <a href="#InventoryDetails" data-icon="back" class="ui-btn-left">Terug</a>

    <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" class="ui-mini ui-btn-right">
        <input id="PageNavigator" type="number" data-role="spinbox" value="1" data-mini="true" style="text-align:center; width:40px;" />
    </div>

</div>
<div data-role="content">
    <div class="scrollable">
        <table data-role="table" class="ui-responsive ui-table ui-table-reflow"><tbody></tbody></table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Current Situation:
[image: Current Situation]

How I want it to be:
[image: How I want it to be]

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is an issue with your header title. If you are starting with an empty title because you need to set it dynamically, you may need either to set a placeholder text, add a span and fill that, or use the `ui-title` class.

Here is an example. Regarding the SpinBox, I just removed your double `controlgroup` nesting

```js
/*
 * ahaith/jquery-mobile-spinbox
 * forked from jtsage/jquery-mobile-spinbox
 * https://github.com/ahaith/jquery-mobile-spinbox
*/

/*
 * jQuery Mobile Framework : plugin to provide number spinbox.
 * Copyright (c) JTSage
 * CC 3.0 Attribution.  May be relicensed without permission/notification.
 * https://github.com/jtsage/jquery-mobile-spinbox
 */

(function($) {
 $.widget( "mobile.spinbox", {
  options: {
   // All widget options
   dmin: false,
   dmax: false,
   step: false,
   theme: false,
   mini: null,
   repButton: true,
   version: "1.4.4-2015092400",
   initSelector: "input[data-role='spinbox']",
   clickEvent: "vclick",
   type: "horizontal", // or vertical
  },
  _decimalPlaces: function (num) {
   var match = (''+num).match(/(?:\.(\d+))?(?:[eE]([+-]?\d+))?$/);
   if (!match) { return 0; }
   return Math.max(
    0,
    (match[1] ? match[1].length : 0)
    - (match[2] ? +match[2] : 0)
   );
  },
  _sbox_run: function () {
   var w = this,
    timer = 150;
    
   if ( w.g.cnt > 10 ) { timer = 100; }
   if ( w.g.cnt > 30 ) { timer = 50; }
   if ( w.g.cnt > 60 ) { timer = 20; }
   
   w.g.didRun = true;
   w._offset( this, w.g.delta );
   w.g.cnt++;
   w.runButton = setTimeout( function() { w._sbox_run(); }, timer );
  },
  _offset: function( obj, direction ) {
   var tmp,
    w = this,
    o = this.options;
    
   if ( !w.disabled ) {
    if ( direction < 1 ) {
     tmp = (parseFloat( w.d.input.val() ) - o.step).toFixed(w.places);
     if ( tmp >= o.dmin ) { 
      w.d.input.val( tmp ).trigger( "change" );
     }
    } else {
     tmp = (parseFloat( w.d.input.val() ) + o.step).toFixed(w.places);
     if ( tmp <= o.dmax ) { 
      w.d.input.val( tmp ).trigger( "change" );
     }
    }
   }
  },
  _create: function() {
   var w = this,
    o = $.extend( this.options, this.element.data( "options" ) ),
    d = {
     input: this.element,
     inputWrap: this.element.parent()
    },
    touch = ( typeof window.ontouchstart !== "undefined" ),
    drag =  {
     eStart : (touch ? "touchstart" : "mousedown")+".spinbox",
     eMove  : (touch ? "touchmove" : "mousemove")+".spinbox",
     eEnd   : (touch ? "touchend" : "mouseup")+".spinbox",
     eEndA  : (touch ? 
      "mouseup.spinbox touchend.spinbox touchcancel.spinbox touchmove.spinbox" :
      "mouseup.spinbox"
     ),
     move   : false,
     start  : false,
     end    : false,
     pos    : false,
     target : false,
     delta  : false,
     tmp    : false,
     cnt    : 0
    };
    
   w.d = d;
   w.g = drag;
   
   o.theme = ( ( o.theme === false ) ?
     $.mobile.getInheritedTheme( this.element, "a" ) :
     o.theme
    );
   
   if ( w.d.input.prop( "disabled" ) ) {
    o.disabled = true;
   }
   
   if ( o.dmin === false ) { 
    o.dmin = ( typeof w.d.input.attr( "min" ) !== "undefined" ) ?
     parseInt( w.d.input.attr( "min" ), 10 ) :
     Number.MAX_VALUE * -1;
   }
   if ( o.dmax === false ) { 
    o.dmax = ( typeof w.d.input.attr( "max" ) !== "undefined" ) ?
     parseInt(w.d.input.attr( "max" ), 10 ) :
     Number.MAX_VALUE;
   }
   if ( o.step === false) {
    o.step = ( typeof w.d.input.attr( "step") !== "undefined" ) ?
     parseFloat( w.d.input.attr( "step" ) ) :
     1;
    w.places = w._decimalPlaces(o.step);
   }
   
   o.mini = ( o.mini === null ? 
    ( w.d.input.data("mini") ? true : false ) :
    o.mini );
    
   
   w.d.wrap = $( "<div>", {
     "data-role": "controlgroup",
     "data-type": o.type,
     "data-mini": o.mini,
     "data-theme": o.theme
    } )
    .insertBefore( w.d.inputWrap )
    .append( w.d.inputWrap );
   
   w.d.inputWrap.addClass( "ui-btn" );
   w.d.input.css( { textAlign: "center" } );
   
   if ( o.type !== "vertical" ) {
    w.d.inputWrap.css( { 
     padding: o.mini ? "1px 0" : "4px 0 3px" 
    } );
    w.d.input.css( { 
     width: o.mini ? "40px" : "50px" 
    } );
   } else {
    w.d.wrap.css( { 
     width: "auto"
    } );
    w.d.inputWrap.css( {
     padding: 0
    } );
   }
   
   w.d.up = $( "<div>", {
    "class": "ui-btn ui-icon-plus ui-btn-icon-notext"
   }).html( "&nbsp;" );
   
   w.d.down = $( "<div>", {
    "class": "ui-btn ui-icon-minus ui-btn-icon-notext"
   }).html( "&nbsp;" );
   
   if ( o.type !== "vertical" ) {
    w.d.wrap.prepend( w.d.down ).append( w.d.up );
   } else {
    w.d.wrap.prepend( w.d.up ).append( w.d.down );
   }
   
   w.d.wrap.controlgroup();
   
   if ( o.repButton === false ) {
    w.d.up.on( o.clickEvent, function(e) { 
     e.preventDefault();
     w._offset( e.currentTarget, 1 ); 
    });
    w.d.down.on( o.clickEvent, function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     w._offset( e.currentTarget, -1 );
    });
   } else {
    w.d.up.on( w.g.eStart, function(e) {
     e.stopPropagation();
     w.d.input.blur();
     w._offset( e.currentTarget, 1 );
     w.g.move = true;
     w.g.cnt = 0;
     w.g.delta = 1;
     if ( !w.runButton ) {
      w.g.target = e.currentTarget;
      w.runButton = setTimeout( function() { w._sbox_run(); }, 500 );
     }
    });
    w.d.down.on(w.g.eStart, function(e) {
     e.stopPropagation();
     w.d.input.blur();
     w._offset( e.currentTarget, -1 );
     w.g.move = true;
     w.g.cnt = 0;
     w.g.delta = -1;
     if ( !w.runButton ) {
      w.g.target = e.currentTarget;
      w.runButton = setTimeout( function() { w._sbox_run(); }, 500 );
     }
    });
    w.d.up.on(w.g.eEndA, function(e) {
     if ( w.g.move ) {
      e.preventDefault();
      clearTimeout( w.runButton );
      w.runButton = false;
      w.g.move = false;
     }
    });
    w.d.down.on(w.g.eEndA, function(e) {
     if ( w.g.move ) {
      e.preventDefault();
      clearTimeout( w.runButton );
      w.runButton = false;
      w.g.move = false;
     }
    });
   }
   
   if ( typeof $.event.special.mousewheel !== "undefined" ) { 
    // Mousewheel operation, if plugin is loaded
    w.d.input.on( "mousewheel", function(e,d) {
     e.preventDefault();
     w._offset( e.currentTarget, ( d < 0 ? -1 : 1 ) );
    });
   }
   
   if ( o.disabled ) {
    w.disable();
   }
   
  },
  disable: function(){
   // Disable the element
   var dis = this.d,
    cname = "ui-state-disabled";
   
   dis.input.attr( "disabled", true ).blur();
   dis.inputWrap.addClass( cname );
   dis.up.addClass( cname );
   dis.down.addClass( cname );
   this.options.disabled = true;
  },
  enable: function(){
   // Enable the element
   var dis = this.d,
    cname = "ui-state-disabled";
   
   dis.input.attr( "disabled", false );
   dis.inputWrap.removeClass( cname );
   dis.up.removeClass( cname );
   dis.down.removeClass( cname );
   this.options.disabled = false;
  }
 });
})( jQuery );
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div data-role="page" id="RoomList">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
      <a href="#InventoryDetails" class="ui-btn-left ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-mini ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-back">Terug</a>
      <h1 class="ui-title"></h1>
      <div class="ui-btn-right">
        <input id="PageNavigator" data-mini="true" type="number" data-role="spinbox" value="1" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
      <div class="scrollable">
        <table data-role="table" class="ui-responsive ui-table ui-table-reflow">
          <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Please note: i used a forked version of SpinBox (stop the click propagation).